# PL/SQL Logical Operators evaluate whole function

Tags: plsql

I know in C like languages logical operators are evaluated one at a time so:

```
false && really_expensive_function()
```

is doesn't result in the function being called (I can't remember the CS name for this). Does the same happen in PL/SQL or do I need to break the IF parts out to separate blocks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CS name is `short-circuiting` ([wikipedia entry on short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) and yes, plsql does exactly that.

Comment: Ace cheers - you never know with some of the crazy things in the world of PL/SQL

Comment: @Chris: That's true :) Have a look at this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021140/why-does-nvl-always-evaluate-2nd-parameter

Comment: +1 Maybe you should update your answer to say "does" rather than "should" to dispel any doubt!

Comment: @Chris, @Tony Andrews: thanks, I've updated the answer to avoid possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking for is "lazy evaluation". You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782465/lazy-evaluation-of-oracle-pl-sql-statements-in-select-clauses-of-sql-queries).